# Regex: match only first instance of a pattern

Tags: regex, sed

Using a regex for a string, we need to remove all text before the first instance of four digits in a row. We have a regex that "sort of" works:

`^((?!\d{4}\w).)*`

Given this string:
`foo-bar-spring_06-2006_02_25.rm`
the desired output is:
`2006_02_25.rm`

That works - if there's only one instance of a four-digit pattern. The string:
`batt-fall_01-2001-11-10_0200-0400.rm` produces this result: `0400.rm`

It should produce:
`2001-11-10_0200-0400.rm`

**Note**: long story, but we cannot use a - or _ as a delimiter.

I feel like we're close. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: are you trying to match the string you want to end up with or the junk string before it?

Comment: Actually, if you need the regex to work with `sed`, none of the answers below are helpful as they are based on PCRE (lookarounds, `\d` shorthand, lazy `*?` quantifier.) What did you do to make `^.*?(?=\d{4})` work? Aren't you using Perl? A basic `grep` can be used here, IMO, `grep -o '[0-9]\{4\}.*' file > newfile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a positive lookahead pattern after a lazily repeated `.` instead:

```
^.*?(?=\d{4})
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/8DZDQp/1

Alternatively, you can group the 4 digits:

```
^.*?(\d{4})
```

and substitute the match with the first group `$1`.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/8DZDQp/3

Comment: The first example is exactly what we needed. Works great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A likely faster option would be to ignore the beginning and undesired part, without using lookarounds, and with a simple expression similar to:

```
(\d{4}.*\..+)$
```

or:

```
(\d{4}.*\.[a-z]+)$
```

End `$` anchor is also unnecessary, without which it would still work.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TWND6v/1)

Comment: Thank you for your response... but I couldn't get the regex to work on our end. I agree it works in the demo, but when we implement it we just couldn't get it to work. The first solution above worked, however, so we're all set. Thank you!